# What is the reason that mock.patch ignores a fully imported function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

Today I realized that it matters for `unittest.mock.patch` how I import a function. Depending on the used way a `mock.patch` call worked or was ignored. In Python we typically import a function with:

- an import statement like `import os` or
- a `from ... import ...` statement like `from os import system`

A `mock.patch` works like a charm if I use `import os`, but it 
was ignored if I patch a `from os import system`.

**Example 1: Using import**

```
import os
from unittest import mock


def echo():
    os.system('echo "Hello"')


with mock.patch('os.system') as mocked:
    print(mocked)
    mocked.side_effect = Exception('Patch works!')
    echo()
```

**Output of example 1**

```
<MagicMock name='system' id='140037358656760'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 12, in <module>
    echo()
  File "/.../config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 6, in echo
    os.system('echo "Hello"')
  File "/.../python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 917, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 973, in _mock_call
    raise effect
Exception: Patch works!
```

**Example 2: Using a full function import and from-import**

When I fully import `os.system` the `mock.patch` ignores the `mocked.side_effect`.

```
from os import system
from unittest import mock


def echo():
    system('echo "Hello"')


with mock.patch('os.system') as mocked:
    print(mocked)
    mocked.side_effect = Exception('Patching does not work!')
    echo()

    print('Patch was ignored!')
```

**Output of example 2**

```
<MagicMock name='system' id='139851175427376'>
Hello
Patch was ignored!
```

In both cases I don't receive an error and `mock` could find `os.system` as a valid path. However, in the second case the function is not properly patched.

- Why `mock.patch` does not patch the function in the second example?
- Are there any implementation specific reasons why the second patch did not work?

Comment: Generally you would use [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) when the object is already imported in the current namespace. It likely won't work on `system` though, since that will be built-in/read only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `from os import system`, you get a variable named `system` pointing to `os.system` function. Later, you *assign*, via patching, a different function to `os.system`, but `system` keeps to point to the old function. This is the same reason why the following works:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

It doesn't happen in the first example, because you reference `os.system` before it is mocked. To fix your second example, I'd go with the following:

```
from os import system
from unittest import mock

def echo():
    system('echo "Hello"')

with mock.patch('__main__.system') as mocked:
    print(mocked)
    mocked.side_effect = Exception('Patching does not work!')
    echo()

    print('Patch was ignored!')
```

This way you make sure you patch the right reference. This is a rather common pattern. If `echo` function were in a file named `echo.py`, the patch call would look like `with mock.patch('echo.system')`.